# List ip in command netstat in linux

Tags: linux, netstat

I have netstat command output like this

```
tcp        0      0 :::80                       192.168.1.1                     LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::22                       192.168.1.2                     LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 ::1:25                      192.168.1.1                     LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::5666                     192.168.1.2                     LISTEN
```

I want a command to match 4 ip to 2 ip like this. Ip the same to match

```
                   192.168.1.1                     LISTEN      
                   192.168.1.2                     LISTEN
```

How to do this? And I want to get step by step once IP ??

Thanks for Answer !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifically for `netstat`'s output, you could use `sed` to extract the IP, which is the 4th field.

```
netstat | sed 's/^\(\S\+\s\+\)\{3\}//'
```

This removes the first 3 fields, leaving you:

```
192.168.1.1                     LISTEN      
192.168.1.2                     LISTEN      
192.168.1.1                     LISTEN      
192.168.1.2                     LISTEN
```

Then you can pipe that through `sort -u`:

```
netstat | sed 's/^\(\S\+\s\+\)\{3\}//' | sort -u
```

resulting in:

```
192.168.1.1                     LISTEN      
192.168.1.2                     LISTEN
```